# How Can I get the raw URL of the uploaded media file?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, media

I have a media field through which I both embed video files from Youtube and upload videos to. I do only want to get the raw URL of the uploaded/embedded videos through the views module but I can't manage it. There are predefined formatters for the video field in the view UI, however the link formatter prints additional data that I don't need. How can I get the raw URL only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module below lets you manipulate the view using php.

http://drupal.org/project/views_php